# ExtJS paging/pagination loads all records at page load

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, extjs

I am trying to set up paging for a grid in my ExtJS app. Let's say I want to show 30 records per page and I have a total of 35 records. No matter what, when I visit the view, the grid always loads all 35 records in the first page although the paging bar shows the presence of two pages (see image).

[image]

The navigation buttons in the paging bar don't work in that, for example, when I hit the "Next page" button, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: store.nextPage is not a function
    at constructor.moveNext (ext-all-debug.js:185314:23)
    at Object.callback (ext-all-debug.js:8705:32)
    at constructor.fireHandler (ext-all-debug.js:144259:17)
    at constructor.onClick (ext-all-debug.js:144241:16)
    at constructor.fire (ext-all-debug.js:20731:42)
    at constructor.fire (ext-all-debug.js:34336:27)
    at constructor.publish (ext-all-debug.js:34296:28)
    at constructor.publishDelegatedDomEvent (ext-all-debug.js:34318:14)
    at constructor.doDelegatedEvent (ext-all-debug.js:34361:16)
    at constructor.onDelegatedEvent (ext-all-debug.js:34349:18)
```

Hitting the "Last page" button doesn't raise an error, yet it just loads the same 35 records.

When I check my webserver logs, I can see that, when I visit the view, my app doesn't just request the first page of record but all of them, which makes no sense:

```
[20/Sep/2023:10:09:55 +0200] "GET /api/requests/?page=1 HTTP/2.0"
[20/Sep/2023:10:09:56 +0200] "GET /api/requests/?page=2 HTTP/2.0"
```

I checked the API output of `/api/requests/?page=1`, generated by Django REST Framework, and it returns

```json
{
    "count": 35,
    "next": "https://xxx.xxx/api/requests/?page=2",
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            ### some data in here ###
        },
    ]
}
```

The `results` array does contain 30 elements.

This is my store

```js
Ext.define('MainHub.store.requests.Requests', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.BufferedStore',
  storeId: 'requestsStore',

  requires: [
    'MainHub.model.requests.Request'
  ],

  model: 'MainHub.model.requests.Request',

  leadingBufferZone: 20,
  pageSize: 30,

 autoload{
    type: 'ajax',
    url: 'api/requests/',
    startParam: false,
    limitParam: false,
    noCache: false,
    enablePaging: true,
    reader: {
      type: 'json',
      rootProperty: 'results',
      totalProperty: 'count'
    }
  },
  remoteFilter: true
});
```

Does anybody know what could be going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure buffered stores are meant to be paginated. See [this example](https://examples.sencha.com/extjs/7.7.0/examples/kitchensink/?classic#buffer-grid). For paged grid you could try a normal `Ext.data.Store`.

Comment: That is indeed the case changing the store to `Ext.data.Store` does that trick, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Peter Koltai mentions in the comments a `Ext.data.BufferedStore` can't be used with pagination, but a `Ext.data.Store` one can.